# Can someone please explain this integral property of odd functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I came across this integral in a text
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{cosx}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}.$$

This was the approach used in the text:

Let $$g(x)= \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\cos x}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}$$

Then $g(x)$ is equivalent to
$$g_{e}(x) + g_{o}(x),$$
that is, it is the sum of an even function $g_e$, and odd function $g_o$.
Then
$$\int_{-1}^{1}g(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}g_{e}(x) \ + \int_{-1}^{1}g_{o}(x)$$
Then it took
$$\int_{-1}^{1}g_{o}(x) \text{ as } 0$$
Talked about symmetry of odd function from the point of view of integrals as area under a graph

Can someone please explain this better—I don't really get  it.
is this as a result of the limit of the integral $(1,-1)$ or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is an odd function then for all $a \geq 0$,
$$I = \int_{-a}^a f(x) \mathrm{dx} = 0$$

Indeed, you can make the substitution $t=-x$ to get
$$I = \int_{-a}^a f(x) \mathrm{dx} = \int_{a}^{-a} -f(-t) \mathrm{dt} = -\int_{-a}^a f(t) \mathrm{dt} = -I$$

So $I=-I$, so $I=0$.